# insert array foreach

Tags: php, mysql, json, foreach

estou tend um problema ao inserir dados no banco com php , tenho um form com varios checkbox , entao quero selecionar mais de 1 checkbox e inserir no banco , fiz assim

form

```
<input type="checkbox" name="f_carteira[]" value="'.$cart['id'].'">
```

action

```
  $carteira = $_POST['f_carteira'];

  if($carteira){
      foreach ($carteira as $car) {

        $cadastrarmensagem = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO mensagem(codigo,conteudomsg,categoria_id,carteira_id,usuario_id) VALUES(:codigo,:conteudo,:categoria,:carteira,:usuarioid)");
  $cadastrarmensagem->bindValue(":codigo",$_POST["f_codigo"]);
  $cadastrarmensagem->bindValue(":conteudo",$_POST["f_msg"]);
  $cadastrarmensagem->bindValue(":categoria",$_POST["f_cat"]);
  $scarteira = implode(",",$carteira);
  $cadastrarmensagem->bindValue(":carteira",$scarteira);
  $cadastrarmensagem->bindValue(":usuarioid",$_POST["f_usuario"]);
  $cadastrarmensagem->execute();
  $linha = $cadastrarmensagem->rowCount();
  if($linha > 0){
     echo "Mensagem Cadastrada com Sucesso";

     header ("Location: ../index.php?pg=mensagens");
  }else {
    echo "Erro";
    //imprimindo erro da variavel de consulta
   print_r($cadastrarmensagem->errorInfo());

    echo "$idlogado";
  }
      }
  }

}else{echo "aconteceu algum erro";}
```

estava tendo problemas porque não estava aceitando array , ai usei json e transformei em strings porem agora ele quer inserir tudo em uma linha só , tipo
1,2,3 no campo da categoria , sendo que quero que ele insira o 1 , pula pra proxima linha insere o 2 , e assim em diante

Comment: Pelo que intendi você deseja usar uma unica coluna para salvar multiplos valores? Se for isso, essa ação viola o dito "FNF (First Normalization Form)". Em resumo: fazer isso pode funcionar, pode ser extremamente estável e nunca apresentar problema, porém não é recomendado. Veja em https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form sobre isso. Você está usando um banco de dados relacional. Crie uma tabela única para armazenar as categorias e associe usando o ID. Dessa forma crie `ID | Categoria` e relacione o ID ao ID da mensagem, depois apenas faça um JOIN entre eles, ou similar.

Comment: poderia me ajudar com um exemplo pratico disso , quero que o cadastrar um topico eu possa selecionar em mais de uma categoria

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, não faça o implode, use a variável $car que possui a sua categoria:

```
  $cadastrarmensagem->bindValue(":categoria",$_POST["f_cat"]);
  //$scarteira = implode(",",$carteira);
  //use a avariavel $car que nao vai mais ser um array
  $cadastrarmensagem->bindValue(":carteira",$car);
  $cadastrarmensagem->bindValue(":usuarioid",$_POST["f_usuario"]);
```

Isso vai permitir que seu codigo funcione. Mas será complexo para gerenciar no futuro. Seguindo o comentário anterior, vejamos:
Pequeno exemplo. Você tem a tabela mensagem:
codigo, conteudomsg, ... categoria
Crie uma outra tabela exemplo, categorias:
id, nome_da_categoria

Você teria todas as categorias salvas na tabela categorias e iria inser na coluna mensagem.categoria (chave estrangeira) o numero equivalente ao id da categoria marcada no checkbox.
Só que a abordagem acima tem um problema você vai inserir os dados da mensagem varias vezes, mudando apenas o valor da categoria. Para evitar isso crie mais uma tabela, exemplo: mensagem_categoria
codigo_mensagem, categoria_id

Então a sua tabela mensagem não teria mais a coluna categoria. Você salvaria a mensagem apenas uma vez. Pegaria o codigo (é o id da tabela mensagem?) e os ids das categorias marcadas nos check box e iria inserir n vezes na tabela mensagem_categoria. Dá uma olhada em relações n para n e n para 1. Há muitos exemplos em php.

Comment: poxa amigo , vlw pelas dicas , tinha testado pensei que estava funcionando , mas ele cadastrou apenas o primeiro registro , o que pode ser ?